# How handle data from sharedpreferences getStringSet?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I had put the Set into sharedpreferences:

```
Set<String> bodyClick = new HashSet<String>();
String panelMarked = new Boolean(panel.marked).toString();

String[] click = {panel.name,panelMarked,clickTimes};

String clickBody = Arrays.toString(click);

bodyClick.add(clickBody);

sharedEditor.putStringSet("click", bodyClick);
```

and this is how I get it:

```
Set<String> click = preferences.getStringSet("click", new HashSet<String>());

if(click != null){

    Iterator<String> iterator = click.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String id = iterator.next();
    }   
}
```

For example this is in the string: [Left rear fender, false, 0]

So far all is okay and working.

But now I want get each element for his own. How can I get "Left rear fener" in a String, "false" in a string and "0" in a string?

Can anybody post some code?

Answer (score 1):

I got it :)

my solution:

```
Set<String> click = preferences.getStringSet("click", new HashSet<String>());

if(click != null){

    Iterator<String> iterator = click.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){

        String id = iterator.next();

        int start = id.indexOf("[") + 1;
        int end = id.indexOf("]")-1;

        String items = String.copyValueOf(id.toCharArray(), start, end);

        String[] ary = items.split(",");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a more efficient way with substring if you're intent on this way, I updated my original answer - it should work the same as your way with less clutter

Answer (score 0):

Why not use String [Split?][1]

```
String id = iterator.next();
id = id.substring(1, id.length()-1)
String[] parts = id.split(",");
String part1 = parts[0]; // Left Near fender
String part2 = parts[1]; // false
```

Comment: ok this worked but I have the brackets "[]" also in the String.

Comment: @silvia_aut try the second part of my answer instead, I edited it

Comment: no it doesn't work . the first solution provides that: part1="[Left rear fender" ... part2="false" ...part3="0]"  Do i dont get the brackets out of it?